# How to Sign .mobileConfiguration Profile ios

Tags: ios

I have create a profile using Apple Configurator 2 to provide password details for wifi connection. And things are working fine. When i try to install the profile in mobile it says that the profile is not signed. I found some link which ask me to do it using openssl bla bla..

Could some one please help me in signing my .mobileConfiguration profile.

Thanks in advance